# Why no one is able to trace who is the Green Hood through the arrow he uses?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, arrow

Some disclosure: I am only through half of the [first season of The Arrow](http://arrow.wikia.com/wiki/Season_1_(Arrow)), so please refrain from posting spoilers (as far as I am concerned)

My question is given that the police is so determine in hunting down the Green Hood, why it can't  make use of the arrows the Green Hood leaves behind every time he is in action? Such sophisticated and rare weapons should be easy to track the manufacturers, and hence nail down the identity of the Green Hood.

Why this is not done?

Comment: He makes them himself. It's not like they didn't try

Comment: Like just about everyone else says, Oliver makes his own arrows.  This is actually shown multiple times throughout the series, even in the later seasons.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**The standard Arrows**

Oliver machines his own arrows, made out of typical metal materials. There's nothing to really trace back to.

**The bow**

Oliver's primary bow early on is the one he returned from Lian Yu with. There's nothing to trace back to that could connect to him.

He does receive another bow later, but from sources not connected to him directly.

**The gadgets and gadget-based arrows**

During the first season, Oliver does use some fancy technology and arrows that he *likely* did not create himself (the hacking arrow, for example). Later on, after Felicity joins the team as a full-time member, she handles most of the technology, but the early tech is *largely* unexplained.

However, as we learn in later seasons,

> Oliver has worked for/with ARGUS in the past.

It is possible that some of his early technology and gadget arrows are leftovers from those days. Given the nature of this source, much of those items will be largely untraceable and unable to connect to Oliver.

Comment: addendum: Oliver has actually used four different bows up to now: a longbow, a recurve bow, a compound bow (Oneida Kestrel from Felicity), and the League of Assassins recurve bow. If you count the modification on the Kestrel as well, we're up to five. Not that it matters for this question.

Comment: I agree with the ARGUS angle explaining where he got his high tech gadgets in season one, but Season 4's flashbacks could provide another source as well, depending on who Oliver meets.